# MySQL error in timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am creating a database for my application. I get this error: MySQL said: Documentation

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(14) NOT NULL,

```
  PRIMARY KEY  (UserID))' at line 4 .
```

This is my sql statement:

```
CREATE TABLE sitheloChat_Users (
  UserID int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  Username varchar(15) NOT NULL default '',
  PreviousUpdate timestamp(14) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (UserID)
);
```

What must i add or edit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the (14) from timestamp

```
 mysql> CREATE TABLE sitheloChat_Users 
( UserID int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
 Username varchar(15) NOT NULL default '', 
PreviousUpdate timestamp NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (UserID) );
    Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)
```

Comment: @sithelo I'm glad, I tested myself before put it here :D

Answer (score 1):

TimeStamp doesn't need the *length* like String (varchar/varchar2).

```
CREATE TABLE sitheloChat_Users ( UserID int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
Username varchar(15) NOT NULL default '', PreviousUpdate timestamp NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (UserID) );
```

Comment: Pleasure !! you shud up the answer if its helpful for you.