# MYSQL Error 1064 in DateTime and TimeStamp

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Good day, I'm creating some tables on my database and when i try to save, it throws this error

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0) NOT NULL , `date_registered` DATETIME NOT NULL , `last_login` TIMESTAMP NOT' at line 1

This sort of error has been debugged [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11362655/mysql-error-in-timestamp) on Stackoverflow before and the solution was to remove the length from the TIMESTAMP column. Other solutions asked the advised that quotes should be removed from column identifiers or ticks should be used instead. Unfortunately, my DATETIME and TIMESTAMP columns do not have lengths and my column identifiers have ticks around them.

Here's what my SQL statement looks like. Can someone please assist?

```sql
CREATE TABLE `inventoryman_db`.`users` 
( `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
`full_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , 
`email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , 
`password` VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL , 
`usertype` ENUM(0) NOT NULL , 
`date_registered` DATETIME NOT NULL , 
`last_login` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL , 
`notes` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'For verification and other purposes, we will store a random key here' , 
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) 
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: enums are strings you need `usertype` ENUM('0')

Comment: Your `ENUM` only has one option. MySQL probably expects 2 or more. Use `TINYINT` if you just want to save a 0

Comment: The issue is actually on the ENUM, not the date_registered. ENUMs are created differently than other columns -- you actually have to specify all the possible values, which should be quoted. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/enum.html. That said, ENUMs are horrendously difficult and annoying (numbers work as strict strings, so `0` does not match `'0'`), and you need to modify the table to add any values. You'd be better off using a string or integer, and control the values with your code.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Initially, i set the ENUM values to 'Admin' and 'User' but somehow the SQL statement didn't capture it, so i had to manually enter them in the statement. I did it this way  `ENUM('Admin', 'User') NOT NULL` and it worked. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

try this, you only need to add quotes in enum('0') as enum consider as string with indexing his arrays.

```
CREATE TABLE `percept`.`users1` ( `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
`full_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , `email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
`password` VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL ,
`usertype` ENUM('0') NOT NULL ,
`date_registered` DATETIME NOT NULL , 
`last_login` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL , 
`notes` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'For verification and other purposes, we will store a random key here' , 
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE = InnoDB `
```

just add quotes in enum